# search for each line from a txt file using grep, speed, and grep settings

Tags: grep

I have a file containing more than 5k+ lines.
The problem is that the script I made takes too long.
Does anyone have any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash
cat filtered.txt | while read line ; do 
    echo $line >> result2.txt
    grep -lr "$line" /somepath/* >> result2.txt;  
done
```

**Second question**: And Is it possible to configure grep for specific *.txt and *.zip files? (i know about zgrep, as far as i know it doesn't support recursion)

I try to search for information, compose and experiment with bash scripts and testing grep/zgrep

Comment: I do not understand your second question at all. You should also not ask multiple questions at once, but create a new question with generous clarification of what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 1):

This command seems to be doing what you need:

```
grep -rf filtered.txt /somepath/ > result2.txt
```

What this does is as follows:
The option `r` searches recursively in the directory specified later in the command.
The option `f` takes a file as an argument, in this case filtered.txt. It searches for every line in that file in the specified directory.
Then you specify the directory to search.
Finally, the result is put out to result2.txt.

I tested this with filtered.txt having the content

```
teststring1
teststring2
```

In my folder I created /somepath/ and put two files there, test1.txt and test2.txt. test1.txt contained "teststring1", test2.txt contained both "teststring1" and "teststring2". This gave the following output in result2.txt:

```
./somepath/test1.txt:teststring1
./somepath/test2.txt:teststring1
./somepath/test2.txt:teststring2
```

This way, you get both the file and which string was found in it, and can reformat that for further processing.